# How does one encrypt site passwords for a Dreamweaver export file?

Tags: dreamweaver

We have over 500 sites that we host. All of their ftp information is in a database. Whenever one of our programmers have to add a site they have to get all the info and set it up. However, I found that you can export them and it has all the info except for one problem. The password is encrypted. I am not trying to hack anything, I want to know how to encrypt our passwords so that we can import them using dreamweavers import feature. Can anyone tell me what encryption they use or a link on how to encrypt. I am not interested in decrypting at all because we already have all of them so it would not do me any good.

Comment: Where is the information stored?  What kind of database?  What do you use to export it?

Comment: It is stored on our website. It is a mysql database. We dont export the information for the ftp info yet...but it looks like all we would have to do is generate xml files in order to be able to import them into dreamweaver but we have to be able to encode our passwords so that dreamweaver will read them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the JavaScript functions on the following page which lists encrypt and decrypt functions for handling Dreamweaver FTP passwords that are found within the XML based .ste site definition files that are exported by Dreamweaver:

http://blog.affirmix.com/2008/08/28/encoded-passwords-in-ste-site-definition-files/